# Windows 10 "unable to connect to this network"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adapter

I read that a lot of people have this problem, but I am not sure if they have it with all networks like I do.

It started happening about 2 days after I installed Windows 10. There are several solutions I have tried, but they only seem to work for a day. Then, on it's own, while my laptop is in use, internet dies on me and I am unable to connect. Restarting my laptop, turning air plane mode on and off and forgetting the network don't work. Note that I have this with all networks in the list. I really can't connect unless I disable my wifi adapter, or reset the settings, or reinstall it.
I have a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter, I run windows 10 Home, version 20H2 (not sure if you need that info for anything)

I have tried several things from this list, but like I said, they only work for a day, or maximum 2:

https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-cant-connect-this-network/

I tried flushing dns, uninstalling the wireless network adapter driver, checking if IPV4 and IPV6 are enabled (which they are), turned IPV6 off, check if the adapter is set to turn off when laptop is not in use (the only thing I was able to do with that is at 5.1 in the article, the rest seemed fine), I checked if I have the latest drivers (which I obviously would have, since I had to uninstall them so often to get my internet to work at all), downloaded and installed them seperately from the Qualcom Atheros site, checked other power options related to the adapter (which would be weird, since it happens when my laptop is in use), ran troubleshoot (which only resets the adapter when connected, and won't work if I can't connect.)

What to do? I never had problems with windows 8.1, but I chose to go to windows 10 for several reasons, and I really don't wanna give that up.

Comment: what's your windows10 version?win10 2004or 20H2? have you ever installed any update package?

Comment: Hi Gloria, it's version 20H2. Another thing I tried today is going to device manager, right clicking my adapter, going to properties and trying to update from there. I read somewhere that if you choose "choose from device" (I forgot how it's called) and then select the Atheros driver, it should work. Sadly this doesn't seem the case as it literally just died on me as I tried to log in to reply to you guys just now...

Comment: Hi, I went to the Atheros site earlier and tried to download the driver for my adapter from there. I either got the wrong thing, or I am a total noob (which is most likely) but when I unzipped the downloaded file I got a bunch of files I don't know how to use. Nothing to install with. Kinda confused on that one. Could it be that I somehow need to download a driver from Asus instead? (since my laptop is an Asus)

Comment: Sorry, another update (if this is even how you do that on this site, I honestly don't know). I read somewhere that people with an Asus laptop who went to windows 10 (upgraded, probably not a fresh install like I did, but I presume in this case it all works just the same) with the exact adapter I have. I went to the Asus site and downloaded the Atheros driver from there. Will keep you posted on if it works now or not.

Comment: I have another update for everyone. It's been a little while and normally I'm pretty sure my internet would have died by now.

I found an article by someone on the Microsoft site who had the same adapter as me, also windows 10, and an Asus laptop, and had the exact same problem. Their solution was simpler than I could have imagined and I am kind of ashamed I didn't think about it earlier: go to the asus website and download the Qualcomm Atheros driver from there, be sure to uninstall the current one before installing the new one. So far my internet has been doing great! Doing great now!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a lot of people are having this problem. Looks like some have solved it by getting an updated driver. Here was on link: http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/downloads/TCK0001000D.exe

I'll see if Atheos has one.....

Comment: This is from another thread:Just test with this driver and works fine : http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/wireless/WIFI_V10_0_0_318_WHQL_Win10.zip

Remove the old driver and launch the setup file.

 (Atheros 10.0.0.318 Win10 32bits from ASUS)

Fix Worked on my Sony Vaio Too!

This solved a similar problem, which occurred after the recent "anniversary update" to Windows 10, on a Sony Vaio which also had the Atheros AR9285 wireless hardware. The Sony Vaio support site did not offer anything to solve this problem so it's great that the Asus solution worked.